# Spatie role plugin for Laravel + seed users with roles, doesn't assignRole

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9, laravel-permission

At laravel 9
I tried to seed users with role

Spatie just procced everything without error, but in database relations between role and users didn't appear in model in table "model_has_role"

`I created role like`

```
$roleName = 'MyRole';
$guardName = 'myGuard';

$roleObj = Role::create(['guard_name' => $guardName, 'name' => $roleName]);
```

`Then created users like`

```
$user = new User($userDatas);
```

`I collected all datas from model what should be filled by`

```
$arrayWithUsersData = [];

foreach($users as $user)
{
   if($users !== NULL)
   {
      $arrayWithUsersData[] = $user->getAttributes();
   }
}
```

`After this i tried to insert all users at once into database so i used`

```
DB::table('users')->insert($arrayWithUsersData);
```

and at end i tried in foreach $users any possible way to assign role
like:

```
$user->assignRole($roleName);
$user->assignRole($roleName, $guardName);
$user->assignRole([$roleName, $guardName]);
$user->assignRole($myRole);
$user->assignRole($myRole, $guardName);
$user->assignRole([$myRole, $guardName]);
$user->syncRoles($myRole);
$user->syncRoles($myRole, $guardName);
$user->syncRoles([$myRole, $guardName]);
```

But nothing gived any error but still didnt create relation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that spatie in assignRole and syncRole valid if model exists

I mean laravel models have property "exists"

theres some code from assignRole function in vendor\spatie\laravel-permission\src\Traits\HasRoles.php

- and syncRoles is wrapper for assignRole

  ```
    $model = $this->getModel();

    if ($model->exists) {
        $this->roles()->sync($roles, false);
        $model->load('roles');
    } else {
        $class = \get_class($model);

        $class::saved(
            function ($object) use ($roles, $model) {
                if ($model->getKey() != $object->getKey()) {
                    return;
                }
                $model->roles()->sync($roles, false);
                $model->load('roles');
            }
        );
    }
  ```

So `DB::table('users')->insert($arrayWithUsersData);` don't change param "exists" in model since it works on raw data

So i had to switch to create users 1 by 1 and save them like

```
$user = new User($userData);
$user->save();
```

And now spatie create relations as it should.